# AngularJS: Collecting additional data asynchronously between the model and view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just starting out with Angular and have come across something regarding asynchronously transforming data between the view and model. Say I have a table that lists users and their names:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Username           First Name          Last Name       |
| -------------------------------------------------------|
| [______________]   ...                 ...             |
| [______________]   ...                 ...
+ -------------------------------------------------------+
```

There is one input per row (in the `username` field).  The `First Name` and `Last Name` fields are plaintext and not editable by the user.  **I would like to be able to type in a username in the input, make a REST API call to find the database record for that user, and display the first and last names automatically (using that record).**

For example, if I type in the username `jsmith`, I want it to go to my API and return an object:

```
{
  "username": "jsmith",
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Smith"
}
```

I then want to display those names in the table, giving me this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Username           First Name          Last Name       |
| -------------------------------------------------------|
| [_jsmith_______]   John                Smith           |
+ -------------------------------------------------------+
```

The input is bound with `ng-model="user"`.  I used `ngModelController` to hook into the model updating process to fetch the user object and swap it out when the given username.

I made a directive, `user-field`:

```
angular.module('directives').directive('userField', ['api', function (api) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return;

      ngModel.$render = function () {
        element.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };

      element.on('blur', function (e) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          api.getUser({
            filter: 'username = "' + element.val() + '"'
          }, function (data) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(data[0]);
            ngModel.$commitViewValue();
            ngModel.$render();

            // returns the entered user object that relates to the username
            console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);
          });
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Here's my input element:

```
<input user-field ng-model="user" />
```

Looking on the console.log in the API callback, the username that the user types in is successfully converted to the user object returned from the API.  However...

**Problem 1**:  It looks like this value never makes it back to the controller itself.  If I `console.log` the $scope of my controller, the value of `user` is `undefined` (not even the regular non-transformed username).

**Problem 2**: Even if I did get this working, I don't think this is exactly how I should be doing it.  If I transform the username string into an object, then the field is going to switch text to '[object Object]' instead of the username.  Is there a good known Angular pattern for doing this sort of thing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As you said in Problem 2 this code would not really work. You have to set $scope variables for firstname and lastname.
I think it would be way easier if you would try to code this problem in the controller itself and not with a directive.

Comment: The code I posted was sort of abbreviated, the `users` model is actually an object.  So a particular input may be bound to `users.thisuser`.  I tried to get the user object to go to `users.thisuser._source`, but could not figure that out.  It's also in an ng-repeat, so I couldn't figure out a way to just get the string version of the correct model name.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**  There is no need to pass an ngModel to directive. Just define an attribute an configure the local scope of your directive.

For example

HTML

```
<userfield user="model"></userfield>
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module('directives').directive('userField', ['api', function (api) {
  return {
  scope: {
         user: '='
  },
  restrict: 'A'

 };
}]);
```

The `'='` creates an two-way-data-binding between the controllers scope and the directive scope for variable `user`.

**Problem 2:** I see no problem with using an object. You can simply access the `name` property of your users object.